# AutoCompleteTextView with JSON

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am trying to use AutoCompleteTextView with Json and i am using this tutorial: [this](https://www.zoftino.com/android-autocompletetextview-web-service-suggestions)

I've got the problem when i try to add data to List:  *foreach not applicable to type 'com.example.program.model.Result'*.  Below is model data and code for AutoCompleteTextView and i added code for Example model .

```
 private void DownloadGames() {

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder()
            .setContext(MainActivity.this)
            .setTheme(R.style.CustomDialog)
            .build();
    alertDialog.setMessage("Loading Data... Please wait...");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialog.show();

    Retrofit retrofit = GamesClient.getRetrofitClient();

    GamesInterface gamesInterface = retrofit.create(GamesInterface.class);

    Call call = gamesInterface.getGamesbyName(gameTitle.getText().toString(), SPINNER_POSITION);

    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();

                if (response.body() != null) {

                    Example example = (Example) response.body();

                   List<String> strings= new ArrayList<String>();

                    for(Result result: ((Example) response.body()).getResult()){
                        strings.add(result.getTitle());
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapteo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, strings.toArray(new String[0]));
                    storeTV.setAdapter(adapteo);


                    contentTitle.setText(example.getResult().getReleaseDate());

                  ...
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Result {

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}

public class Example {

@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private Result result;


public Result getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(Result result) {
    this.result = result;
}

}
```

Comment: ((Example) response.body()).getResult()) it should be list of Result, check this I think you are making mistake here

Comment: Can you post  the full code of first block of code please? And from where you get that `result`?

Comment: I updated code for the first block. I must add that everything works fine without AutoCompleteTextView. I just want to add autosuggestions.

Comment: You should update your question if there is no more problem with Result as not List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expect List of objects but observe single object in **Example class**. If your API throws List of Results then change Example class with

```
public class Example {

     @SerializedName("result")
      @Expose
      private List<Result> result;

      public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
      } 

      public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
      }

     }
```

And change this line

```
for(Result result: ((Example) response.body()).getResult()){
                        strings.add(result.getTitle());
                    }
```

with

```
 for(Result result: example.getResult()){
                        strings.add(result.getTitle());
                    }
```